# CodeIgniter Route rsegment() Duplicates End Value

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

Using CodeIgniter route I have this rule

```
$route['^(?!login|profile|signup|notification|member).*/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$2/$0/$1/$3";
```

My URL would be something like this `http://example.com/memberfolder/7/view_document/WjbZpAPHM6`

So basically the code should route to `view_document()` method in the home class with `rsegment(5)` being value `WjbZpAPHM6`

However, when the code goes to the home class, `rsegment(5)` value is `view_document`.

As you can see for my routing rule I should only have 5 rsegments, so when I printed all rsegments I got this:

> home view_document memberfolder 7 view_document WjbZpAPHM6

As you can see my `rsegment(5)` is a duplicate or `rsegment(2)`. Even though I should have only 5 rsegments, my document file value `WjbZpAPHM6` is stored in `rsegment(6)`.

Any advice on how to correct `rsegment(5)` to be the value of the document name rather then `view_document`

Also, my `.htaccess` is as such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is the `?!` in your route how it exists in your app? Because that's a zero-width negative look-behind, which would effectively break that route entirely.

Comment: @Cryode `?<!` is negative look-behind and it has restrictions like fixed width, however a negative look-ahead `?!` can contain any regular expression.

Comment: Whoops I meant look-ahead. Too much regex in my noggin. Either way, it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(:any)` will match any character EXCEPT `/` in *CI 3.0* or WILL match `/` in *CI <= 2.1.3*

So to make it compatible for both versions we will just manually put in the character match without using CI's shorthand syntax by using `[^/]+` in place of `:any`. Note we do not put in parentheses as we do not want to create a backreference.

Also you do not put `^` as CI automatically puts it in. In addition, you have your backreferences wrong. You don't use `$0`, you start with `$1` and work up. I changed them to correct numbers.

---

Your route should be this:

```
$route['((?!login|profile|signup|notification|member)|member[^/]+)/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$3/$1/$2/$4";
```

So for the following URL example:

`memberfolder/7/view_document/WjbZpAPHM6`

The backreferences will be:

```
$1 = memberfolder
$2 = 7
$3 = view_document
$4 = WjbZpAPHM6
```

Now to build your request:

`home/$3/$1/$2/$4` becomes `home/view_document/memberfolder/7/WjbZpAPHM6`

Making the following rsegments:

```
rsegment(1) = home
rsegment(2) = view_document
rsegment(3) = memberfolder
rsegment(4) = 7
rsegment(5) = WjbZpAPHM6
```

Comment: In CI <= 2.1.3, `:any` is directly replaced with `.+`, which WILL match forward slashes. As of CI 3.0 this has been changed to exclude slashes.

Comment: @Cryode you're correct, I had checked the 3.0 source. Will update answer.

Comment: The colon was just saying not to make a backreference for that paretheses group. Since it was changed to an exclamation which is a look-ahead we don't need to do that as those don't automatically create a backreference anyway. In CI 2.1.3 and less `:any` is equal to `.*` in CI 3.0 it is equal to `[^/]+` the correct one to use is the 3.0 method. so to make your route compatible we just manually put it in. `.*` will match 1 or more of any char including `/` and will continue matching other segments because of that. By using `[^/]+` you tell it to match 1 or more of any char EXCEPT `/`

Comment: As for your other question you don't have to do that. Just do change `member[^/]+` to `(?:member|home)[^/]+` as it will match `homeANYCHARS` just like currently it will match `memberANYCHARS` just add to the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, if i have any other issues regarding this can i give you a pm.

As i am not very familiar with regular expressions yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about CodeIgniter, but I think, you should replace

```
$route['^(?!login|profile|signup|notification|member).*/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$2/$0/$1/$3";
```

with this

```
$route['^(?!login|profile|signup|notification|member).*/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/$2/$0/$1/$3';
```

Comment: Unfortunately a ' and " does not make a difference. i've tried it already but the duplicate value is still there